# Which action we should use to add user to a security group (non-office 365 group) using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, azure-ad

We have some security groups inside our AD. Some of them are mail enabled the others are not. now we want to add user to those security groups using power automate.

So which action we need to use:

[image]

OR

[image: johnjohn123_1-1659733097669.png]

**EDIT**

- This is the mail enabled security group::

[image]

- This is the security group:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"**Add member to groups**" action will only work for Office 365 Group (which are mail enabled)

"**Add user to Group**" action will work for both the cases i.e. Office 365 Group (Mail enabled) or Normal security Group

So in your case if you have both the scenario then you should use action "Add User to group".

Make sure that "Add user to group" action will except only "GroupId" and "UserId" as input so you will need user additional actions to grab those details based on group name and user principal name.

**Official Documentation**

**Add User to group (Azure AD)**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/#add-user-to-group

**Add Member to group(Office 365 Groups)** : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365groups/#add-member-to-group

Hope it will help to you. Please mark this as answer if it works for you.

Comment: but based on my test, the "Add Member to group" will work in-case the security group is NOT mail enabled, while if it mail enabled security group i will get this error `Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list.`

Comment: i also tried to add members inside the mail-enabled security group  using the Azure Add user to group, and i get the same error

Comment: Can you add screen shot of Security Group if possible so that I can get more idea what kind of group you have?

Comment: ok updated my question with 2 screen shots

Answer (score 1):

**For security groups**:

You can use "Add user to Group" action from "Azure AD" connector in Power Automate.

[image]

**For mail-enabled security groups**:

Mail-enabled security groups are owned by Exchange Online. As per my test you cannot add users to these group using Azure AD - "Add user to Group" action or Office 365 groups - "Add member to group" action.

Comment: so what are the options to add members to mail-enabled security groups using cloud flow?

Comment: Unable to find any action for this case in cloud flow. As per the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/14899#issuecomment-978549997), only way to add users to a mail-enabled security group programmatically requires a PowerShell script. Related: [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-mail-enabled-security-groups).

Comment: ok thanks, but per my knowledge we can not call powershell script from could flow?

Comment: Yes, no direct (standard) action to run PowerShell. But there are ways to do it using Azure & premium services. Check [this](https://ashiqf.com/2020/05/26/execute-sharepoint-online-powershell-scripts-using-power-automate/) and [this](https://practical365.com/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-to-automate-manual-processes-in-office-365/) for reference.

Comment: Hi @JohnJohn, does this help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.